# How to enter suggestions

Tags: support

What can I do when I don't have a question but actually some kind of advice for hopefully a number of superusers around there? Should I first ask the question, wait a bit and than answer my own question? Make two accounts one for asking one for answering? (probably a bad idea). Or is it not really covered by these boards?

Comment: Answering your own questions using a sock puppet account is definitely not a good idea. Having your questions only ever answered by one particular user is a sign of voting fraud and is not appreciated here. Answering your own questions using your own (only?) account is fine and keeps everything out in the open: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 6):

With questions like this - the help and the tour are your starting points.

> I don't have a question but actually some kind of advice for hopefully a number of superusers around there?

Er... depends. Can you frame it as a question? Is it a solution for a real problem with a real solution?

> Should I first ask the question, wait a bit and than answer my own question?

[Self answering is fine](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) - you can even tick a little check mark to self answer immediately if you want.

> Make two accounts one for asking one for answering? (probably a bad idea).

In this case, not a good idea. Some folk *do* have alternate accounts and you [can find the official rules on that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685)

These aren't boards, these are Q&A sites, and we do work a bit differently. Does look like you *roughly* get that though.